# Connection between servlet and HTML form doesn't work

Tags: java, html, servlets

I encountered a problem in the connection between an HTML page and a servlet in Java. I already had this problem a few days ago but it was my mistakes in project management.
Now, it seems to me that I have done everything properly but I cannot deal with it.
In particular I'm creating an HTML page that contains a form with the action that call a servlet. My HTML page is on the "Web content" directory automatically created by Eclipse when I create a new Dynamic web project.

my WebServlet annotation is "@WebServlet(/UploadBook)" and the action on the form tag is "action=UploadBook".

When I click on the submit button the page this is the message that I receive:

Not Found
The requested URL /coltraneShop/Administrator/adminColtraneShop/WebContent/UploadBook was not found on this server.

I'm using Firefox on MacOS and apache webServer is started. I added, moreover, the Dynamic web project on server tomcat 9 from Eclipse and started it without problem.

This is my servlet Java code:

```
package insertion;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.sql.Statement;

import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

@WebServlet("/UploadBook")
public class UploadBook extends HttpServlet {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;


protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
    response.setContentType("text/html;charset=UTF-8");
    PrintWriter out= response.getWriter();
    Long productCode= (long) 0;

    //Fetch data from HTML form method POST
    String title= request.getParameter("Title");
    String quantity= request.getParameter("Quantity");
    String yearOfPublication= request.getParameter("yearOfPublication");

    String genre= request.getParameter("Genre");
    String numPages= request.getParameter("numPages");
    String ISBN= request.getParameter("ISBN");
    String publisher= request.getParameter("publisher");

    String writerName1= request.getParameter("writerName1");
    String writerSurname1= request.getParameter("writerSurname1");
    String writerDateOfBirth1= request.getParameter("writerDateOfBirth1");
    String writerGender1= request.getParameter("writerGender1");

    Connection connection= null;

    //Connect to DB
    try {
        connection= connectDB();
    } 
    catch (ClassNotFoundException | SQLException ConnectionException) {
        System.out.println("Error in connection!");
        out.print("Connection to DB is not avaiable. " + ConnectionException.getMessage());
    }

    //Send query to DB
    try {   
        //Preparing statement and query to DB
        PreparedStatement statementProduct = connection.prepareStatement("INSERT INTO coltraneShop.Product (Category, `Title`, Quantity, `Year of publication`)"
                + "VALUES ('Book', ?, ?, ?);", Statement.RETURN_GENERATED_KEYS);

        //Passing parameters
        statementProduct.setString(1, title);
        statementProduct.setInt(2, Integer.parseInt(quantity));
        statementProduct.setInt(3, Integer.parseInt(yearOfPublication));

        int affectedRows= statementProduct.executeUpdate();
        if(affectedRows == 0)
            throw new SQLException("Creating product failed, no rows affected.");

        //Return ID of product insert in DB
        ResultSet resultSet = statementProduct.getGeneratedKeys();
        if(resultSet.next())
            productCode= resultSet.getLong(1);  

        statementProduct.close();
        out.print("<p>Added a product</p><br>");

        PreparedStatement statementBook = connection.prepareStatement("INSERT INTO coltraneShop.Book VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?);");
        statementBook.setString(1, genre);
        statementBook.setInt(2, Integer.parseInt(numPages));
        statementBook.setLong(3, Long.parseLong(ISBN));
        statementBook.setString(4, publisher);
        statementBook.setLong(5, productCode);

        int affectedRowsBook= statementBook.executeUpdate();
        if(affectedRowsBook == 0)
            throw new SQLException("Creating book failed, no rows affected.");

        statementBook.close();
        out.print("<p>Added a book</p><br>");


        PreparedStatement statementWriter1 = connection.prepareStatement("INSERT INTO coltraneShop. VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?);");
        statementWriter1.setString(1, writerName1);
        statementWriter1.setString(2, writerSurname1);
        statementWriter1.setString(3, writerDateOfBirth1);
        statementWriter1.setString(4, writerGender1);

        int affectedRowswriter1= statementWriter1.executeUpdate();
        if(affectedRowswriter1 == 0)
            throw new SQLException("Creating writer failed, no rows affected.");

        statementWriter1.close();
        out.print("<p>Added a writer</p><br>");

        int elementInRequest= request.getContentLength();
        if(elementInRequest > 10) {

            int numAdditionalWriter= (elementInRequest - 10) / 4;

            for(int i=0; i<(numAdditionalWriter); i++) {
                PreparedStatement statementAdditionalWriter= connection.prepareStatement("INSERT INTO coltraneShop. VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?);");
                statementAdditionalWriter.setString(1, ("writerName" + (i+2)));
                statementAdditionalWriter.setString(2, ("writerSurname" + (i+2)));
                statementAdditionalWriter.setString(3, "writerDateOfBirth" + (i+2));
                statementAdditionalWriter.setString(4, "writerGender" + (i+2));

                int affectedRowsAdditionalWriter= statementAdditionalWriter.executeUpdate();
                if(affectedRowsAdditionalWriter == 0)
                    throw new SQLException("Creating addtional writer failed, no rows affected.");

                statementAdditionalWriter.close();
                out.print("<p>Added a writer</p><br>");
            }
        }

    } 
    catch (SQLException exceptionInQuery) {
        System.out.println("Error in the query");
        out.print("Error in statement or process of sending queries to the database. " + exceptionInQuery.getMessage());
    }

    try {
        connection.close();
    } 
    catch (SQLException closeConnectionException) {
        System.out.println("Problem in closing connection");
        out.print("Problem in closing connection. " + closeConnectionException.getMessage());
    }

    out.close();
}

private Connection connectDB() throws ClassNotFoundException, SQLException {
        Connection connection= null;
        Class.forName("com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver");
        connection= DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/coltraneShop?useTimezone=true&serverTimezone=UTC", "root", "");
        return connection;
}
```

}

And This is my HTML form code:

```
<head>
    <title>Insert book in the database</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <!--Bootstrap CSS-->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-MCw98/SFnGE8fJT3GXwEOngsV7Zt27NXFoaoApmYm81iuXoPkFOJwJ8ERdknLPMO" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <script src="administrator.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
    <form action="UploadBook" method="POST">
        <div class="container">

            <div class="form-group">
                <label> <strong>Title:</strong> </label>
                <input type="text" name="Title" class="form-control" placeholder="Title of book" maxlength="50" required>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
                <label> <strong>Quantity:</strong> </label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" name="Quantity" placeholder="Max quantity in stock can be 999" maxlength="3" pattern="[0-9]{1,3}" onkeydown="return isNumberKey(event)" required></input>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
                <label> <strong>Year of publication:</strong> </label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" name="yearOfPublication" placeholder="Year of publication" maxlength="4" pattern="[0-9]{1,4}" onkeydown="return isNumberKey(event)" required></input>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
                <label> <strong>Genre:</strong> </label>
                <select class="form-control" name= "Genre" required>
                    <option value="History" >History</option>
                    <option value="Fantasy">Fantasy</option>
                    <option value="Child">Child</option>
                    <option value="Art">Art</option>
                    <option value="Music">Music</option>
                    <option value="Thriller">Thriller</option>
                    <option value="Travel">Travel</option>
                    <option value="Biography">Biography</option>
                    <option value="Poetry">Poetry</option>
                    <option value="Romance">Romance</option>
                    <option value="Science">Science</option>
                </select>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
                <label> <strong>Number of pages:</strong> </label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" name="numPages" placeholder="Max length: 99.999 pages" maxlength="5" pattern="[0-9]{1,5}" onkeydown="return isNumberKey(event)" required></input>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
                <label> <strong>ISBN:</strong> </label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" name="ISBN" placeholder="13-digit code" maxlength="13" pattern="[0-9]{1,13}" onkeydown="return isNumberKey(event)" required></input>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
                <label> <strong>Publisher:</strong> </label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" name="publisher" placeholder="The name of the publishing house" maxlength="30" required></input>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
                <label> <strong>Writer's name:</strong> </label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" name="writerName1" placeholder="The name of the Writer" maxlength="20" required></input>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
                <label> <strong>Writer's surname:</strong> </label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" name="writerSurname1" placeholder="The surname of the Writer" maxlength="20" pattern="[A-z]{1,20}" required></input>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
                <label> <strong>Writer's date of birth:</strong> </label>
                <input type="date" class="form-control" name="writerDateOfBirth1"></input>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
                <label> <strong>Writer's gender:</strong> </label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" name="writerGender1" placeholder="Gender of writer: can be 'M' or 'F' or 'N(on defined)'" maxlength="1" pattern="^(M|F|N)" ></input>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group" id="containerWriters">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-success" id="addWriterButton" onclick="addWriter()"> Add Writer </button>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-danger" id="removeWriterButton" onclick="removeWriter()"> Remove Writer </button>
            </div>

            <!--Submit all data -->
            <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg btn-block" value="Insert" id="submit"></input>

        </div> <!--Container div-->
    </form>

    <!-- Bootstrap jQuery, Ajax and JavaScript-->
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.3/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ZMP7rVo3mIykV+2+9J3UJ46jBk0WLaUAdn689aCwoqbBJiSnjAK/l8WvCWPIPm49" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-ChfqqxuZUCnJSK3+MXmPNIyE6ZbWh2IMqE241rYiqJxyMiZ6OW/JmZQ5stwEULTy" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>
```

Thank a lot for helping me.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you loaded file directly from file system and the tried to call this servlet. This is not correct. Load this HTML via your Tomcat, i.e. via URL like

`http://localhost:8080/.../xxx.html`.

If because of some reason you still want to use static HTML without Tomcat, then change servlet URL in your HTML to a full URL like following:

`<form action="http://localhost:8080/.../UploadBook" method="POST">`

If none of this is your case, then provide more info, how exactly are you loading HTML in you browser.

Comment: Ok if I do it, works! But I'm trying to not do as you suggested because if I change the structure of my path in my project it won't still work. in fact I've always seen it done as I was trying to do myself. But if you explain well me why your approach is better I will be happy to learn. Thanks a lot.

Comment: I'd suggest you to learn how web applications work. Briefly: You package your code (.class files of servlets, static HTML, JSPs, JavaScript, images, CSS) into a WAR and deploy it on some server. Your users will get NO access to your disk. They will load HTML via your application server, like `https://your.server.com/yourapp/.../xxx.html`. That's why it make sense to test it in the same mode that will be later used on the normal server.